# Drywall fix doesn't match ceiling

Tags: drywall

Repairing a textured ceiling. However the new drywall mud stayed gray rather than turning white.  I've never had this happen before, why is it gray? it isn't old or moldy.  it was mixed just for this job. It basically looks like it didn't dry at all though it is. What do I do to make it match the rest of the ceiling?

Comment: If it's dry and hard, just prime and paint. Not every mud changes color.

Answer (score 1):

Mudding is only one step in the repair process.

Patch repair, tape, Mud, Texture, Primer, Paint.

Buy a can [Homax spray texture](https://www.homaxproducts.com/wall-ceiling-textures/aerosol-wall-textures/pro-grade-wall-texture-orange-peel-water-based-25oz) and practice on piece of cardboard before doing the patched area. It is an acquired skill, make adjustments to the nozzle to get the matching texture size you need.

I usually start with a fine/small first, let that dry and then a medium on top of that.